# QGIS: plotting real time lat/lon GPS input on a different projection

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinate-system, tracking

I'm trying to plot realtime GPS over a satellite image in QGIS 1.8. The GPS data is coming in as NMEA lat/lon from a Garmin Etrex. This works when the image is in WGS84 lat/lon projection and therefore the coordinate systems match.

Unfortunately, I will be using this in high latitudes and WGS84 becomes unusable. I'd much rather have the image in something like UTM 24N or polar stereographic.

Does anyone know a way to get the GPS to plot in the right location?

I don't seem to be able to change the coordinate system that the GPS outputs, only the on-GPS display. Suggestions for either Linux or Windows welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPS data comes in WGS84, so the **layer** CRS should be EPSG:4326.

But you can choose for **project** CRS any CRS you like . With `On the fly` enabled, they should work together.

Comment: Ah apologies, you are quite right. There was a problem with the projection of my base image. Thanks!

Comment: More specifically I was testing it using an OS raster for the UK and accidentally set the projection to "OSGB 1936" EPSG:4277 and not "OSGB 1936/ British National Grid" EPSG:27700. Now working perfectly.